# Probe/Sensor-design for pulsed electromagnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-circuits, electric-fields

So I have a wire/coil, acting as a sender, which has a pulsed signal as described below. I would like to build a sensor/probe that can detect the electric field at a distance, where the primary goal is to get a V/m reading. Distance from coil I need to measure is 0 to 10cm, in steps of ~1-2cm.

Question is what type of designs may achieve this, starting at the simplest/cheapest solutions? Hand-built/standard components/IC. I could build several if there are useful alternatives.

Obviously since I ask, I got a bit of reading to do. But hope for some guidance so I know what to focus on. Like type of designs, their pros/cons/challenges, and how certain parameters of signal/design are governing and related.

```
Sender-coil and it's signal:
(Brackets show desired range the sensor may ideally cover, but not essential)

Coil:  1 turn (1-20), Dia=150mm
Waveform: Positive Square wave
Freq:  60Hz (1-100) 
Pulse width:  300ns (50ns-1ms)
Rise/fall time: 10ns (3-30ns) 
Peak Voltage:   9V  (3-50V)
```

Comment: This is better suited for electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Brionius; I tried there first actually, without luck.. :)  I guess I'll just have to go study antennas.

Comment: Why not use a dipole or monopole antenna?  You can build those out of a single stacer of some conducting (higher conductivity = better) material (e.g., copper).  If you are only interested in high frequency signals, then antennas work great.  If you are set on using a loop, then read up on search coils (though you will be measuring $\partial \mathbf{B} / \partial t$).  Note that it is a real pain to get the sign right in those instruments.